# Copy constructor - is the base one called before the derived one?

Tags: c++

I don't understand how the copy order works within a class hierarchy

This code:

```
class Base
{
protected:
  void myBaseMethod()
  {
    cout << "basemethod";
  }

  Base()  { cout << "default constructor - base"; }
  ~Base() { }

  Base(Base& other)
  {
    cout << "copy constructor - base";
  }
  Base& operator= (Base const &)
  {
    cout << "assignment operator - base";
  }

};

class Derived :  private Base
{
public:
  Derived()
  {
    cout << "default constructor - derived";
  }
};

int main()
{

  Derived eaObj;

  Derived efu = eaObj;

  return 0;
}
```

outputs "default constructor  - base" "default constructor - derived" as expected then it outputs "copy constructor - base".

Which copy constructors are called when I copy an object? First the base class ones then the derived class ones? What if they're virtual?

Comment: `What if they're virtual?` Constructors cannot be virtual.

Comment: @Fiktik He probably means virtual inheritance:  what if the base class is virtual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The copy constructor called is that of the static type of the
object, in your case, `Derived`.  The compiler generated copy
constructor calls the copy constructors of each of the bases,
and since you didn't provide a copy constructor for `Derived`,
this is what happens in your case.

If *you* define the copy constructor, you need to explicitly
call that of the base; otherwise, the default constructor of the
base will be called.  (In a few rare cases, this is what is
wanted.  But not usually.)

If the inheritance is virtual, constructors for the virtual
bases are called from the most derived class.  Copy constructors
work like any other constructor here: if the most derived class
has a compiler generated copy constructor, it will call the copy
constructor of each of the virtual bases; if it has a user
defined copy constructor, it's up to the programmer to call the
copy constructors of the bases.  (In my experience, it's rare
for virtual bases to contain data members, so the copy
constructor and the default constructor both do the same thing.)

Answer (score 4):

> Which copy constructors are called when I copy an object? First the base class ones then the derived class ones? What if they're virtual?

In your case, the copy-ctor of `Derived` is called, since you are copying a `Derived` object. However, since you did not define that copy-ctor, the compiler generates one for you. That generated copy-ctor copies all parts of the `Derived` object, including its `Base` subobject. That is where you get the output from.

The constructors are not calle *after* another. The `Base` constructor is called *inside* the `Derived` constructor, in the initialization list, before `Derived`'s constructor body is entered. This applies for all constructors, not only for copy-ctors. If you have not mentioned the `Base` part in a `Derived` constructor's init list, `Base`s default constructor gets called implicitly by the compiler.

Wrt virtual constructors: there are no virtual constructors in C++.